# Yahoo is spamming my server e-mail despite 10/10 rating

Tags: email, yahoo-mail

All my customer's e-mails that use my e-mail server is going to spam. Despite the e-mail having 10/10 rating, having all the SPF and DKIM records configured correctly. Despite yahoo mail holders constantly unspamming the e-mails and whitelisting as well. Yahoo doesn't have a developer forum like Google.

This only happens to people who have yahoo mail. Gmail, hotmail, msn, aol all delivering fine to inbox.

How would you go about this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Contact Yahoo; it could be someone is spoofing your "from" line or that the subject is objectionable.

Comment: They are not responding to any e-mail requests. Subjects are very different. Even if client responds to yahoo e-mail, response will end up in spam